# Seeking an example using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

A tool I'm working on is required to walk through a directory structure, filter out certain file types and do something (taking a rather long time compared to the tree walking) with them. Naturally, I implemented a Callable interface and run the workload asynchronously using a run-time defined allotted amount of threads.

My inquiry is about the following aspects:

- How could the following working code be rewritten to use 
  [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) for the sake of learning something interesting?
- It seems my thread timer is wrongly implemented. It only 
  displays a given workthread's last elapsed time. How would I elegantly fix 
  this?

Here is the working code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class DirWalkTest {
    @Test
    public void DirWalkNonBlocking() {
        final String directory = "./test/pdfWalker";

        class myCallable implements Callable<Boolean>{
            private final File file;

            public myCallable(File f) {
                this.file = f;
            }

            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                initTimerNS("DirWalkNonBlocking-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
                formatter.format("Callback [%s] invoked: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), file.toString());
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                formatter.format("Callback [%s] finished: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), file.toString());
                //This seems to be synchronised as opposed to the individual System.out.printf()
                System.out.printf("%s", sb.toString());
                getElapsedTimeNS("DirWalkNonBlocking-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return true;
            }
        }

        //TODO: CompletableFuture is the new kid on the block ...
        //      http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        System.out.printf("Running thread pool with %s threads%n", Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        initTimerNS("overall");
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(directory)).
                    filter(Files::isRegularFile).
                    filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")).
                    forEach(p -> executor.submit(new myCallable(p.toFile())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.printf("DirWalkNonBlocking() completed in %.2fms%n", getElapsedTimeNS("overall") / 10E5);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : end.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            if (key.startsWith("DirWalkNonBlocking-")) {
                System.out.printf("Run: thread=%s elapsed=%.2fms%n", key, (end.get(key) - start.get(key)) / 10E5);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Long> start = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public static Map<String, Long> end = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void initTimerNS(String key) {
        start.put(key, System.nanoTime());
    }

    public static double getElapsedTimeNS(String key) {
        end.put(key, System.nanoTime());
        return end.get(key) - start.get(key);
    }
}
```

The following structure is used for testing this (under ./test/pdfWalker):

```
$ find . -printf "type=%y: file=%p\n" | sort
type=d: file=.
type=d: file=./1
type=d: file=./1/2
type=d: file=./1/2/3
type=d: file=./1/dir.pdf
type=f: file=./1/2/3/iwke
type=f: file=./1/2/3/j.pdf
type=f: file=./1/2/g.pdf
type=f: file=./1/9843ii.pdf
type=f: file=./1/ijj
type=f: file=./1/kk.pdf
```

The output of the test code is as follows:

```
Running thread pool with 8 threads
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/1.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/1.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/1/9843ii.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/1/9843ii.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/3.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/3.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/1/2/3/j.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/1/2/3/j.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/1/2/g.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/1/2/g.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/1/kk.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/1/kk.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/2.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/2.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/4.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/4.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/7.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/7.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/8.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/8.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/5.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/5.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] invoked: ./test/pdfWalker/6.pdf
Callback [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5] finished: ./test/pdfWalker/6.pdf
DirWalkNonBlocking() completed in 3131.57ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7 elapsed=1501.86ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 elapsed=1504.18ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5 elapsed=1502.50ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 elapsed=1502.93ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 elapsed=1502.35ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 elapsed=1502.06ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 elapsed=1501.74ms
Run: thread=DirWalkNonBlocking-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0 elapsed=1501.29ms
```

Comment: ... output written by System.out.* is synchronized ... I don't want to use synchronized()... Huh?

Comment: I hate you burst your bubble, but [`StringBuffer` is `synchronized`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#270). That aside, it doesn't seem to me that this question is [a good fit for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It seems like you want us to review your code. If that's the case, your question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. And no, I don't want anybody to review my code. I'd like to learn something new every now and then, and as such I fail to see how this question does not belong here. It seems it would make a better fit if I'd remove the synchronized part from my question.

Answer (score 2):

instead of creating Callable instances which are submitted to the Executor

```
.forEach(p -> executor.submit(new myCallable(p.toFile())))
```

you create Future instances.

```
.forEach(p -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> work(p.toFile()), executor)
```

where `work` is a function that would contain the code from `Callable::call`.

Note that I suggest `runAsync` here because you do not use the return value of your Callable (Boolean). If you wanted to use the result of a `CallableFuture` computation, you would use `supplyAsync` instead, which gives access to the result upon completion.

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> resultHandle = 
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> true);

//Now, either block and wait for the result
Boolean result = resultHandle.join();
System.out.println(result);

//Or attach a "completionListener"
resultHandle.thenAccept(result -> System.out.println(result));
```